# Error related to Google Cloud when running rgee function (Google Earth Engine in R)

Tags: r, gcloud, google-earth-engine, rgee

I have installed the `rgee` package in RStudio, but when running `ee_initialize()` before running Google Earth Engine functions, I get the following error stating that I have not installed gcloud, even though I have installed it. Does anyone know the cause of this issue? Are there additional specific components I need to install in gcloud?

```
> library(rgee)
> library(tidyrgee)
> library(sf)
> library(tidyverse)
> devtools::load_all()
i Loading surveyGEER
> rgee::ee_Initialize()
-- rgee 1.1.5 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- earthengine-api 0.1.331 -- 
 √ user: not_defined
 √ Initializing Google Earth Engine:Fetching credentials using gcloud
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  Exception: gcloud command not found. Please ensure that gcloud is installed.
More information: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/python_install
```